# How to draw border to an imageview with Coil in Android?

Tags: android, imageview, border-image, circleimage, coil

I am using 'Coil' to have circular imageview. I want to draw a circular border to this circular imageview. How to do it with using Coil?

This is where I load the image:

```
 binding.imageviewFaceDetectionSelfieCircle.load(R.drawable.ic_avatar) {
            transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
        }
```

This is where the image^s XML:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_face_detection_selfie_circle"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageview_face_detection_id_card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no such option in `Coil`. To draw border you can use `ShapableImageView` from `"com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0"`

```
    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/blue"
        app:strokeWidth="3dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the old question, but there is no particular answer.
I will share my variant

- add the `BorderedCircleCropTransformation` class to your project
  https://gist.github.com/sergestanislavsky/52c76a5a0b61cf5f76e39724916c6f88

An example of using

```
....
if (isRoundedImage) {
    transformations(
       BorderedCircleCropTransformation(
       dpToPx(LocalContext.current, borderImageWidth), borderImageColor.toArgb())
    )
}
....
fun dpToPx(context: Context, dp: Int): Float {
    return dp * context.resources.displayMetrics.density
}
....
```

p.s. more variants are there https://stackoverflow.com/a/78075887/916826

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Coil's Pull Requests, you can see [here](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/pull/508) that the user *t-kurimura* tried to implement the functionality that you want. See his [commit](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/pull/508/commits)  and make your own *[CircleCropTransformation](https://github.com/t-kurimura/coil/blob/a011c6a9487d4099cea73bab3d5fcd06c9795c62/coil-base/src/main/java/coil/transform/CircleCropTransformation.kt)* class. It's very simple and it works! I made it in my project!