# Rounded corners of image in Jetpack Glance Widget

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, glance-appwidget, glance

Is there any way how to make image corners in Jetpack Glance Widget rounded?
I know there is a GlanceModifier method `cornerRadius`, but this is available only in higher versions (S+).

Comment: I suspect that you would need to round the image itself, before you applied it to your app widget using Glance. That modifier relies on new methods on `RemoteViews`, [such as `setViewOutlinePreferredRadius()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#setViewOutlinePreferredRadius(int,%20float,%20int)), which is why there is a API limit applied on the modifier.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a `Coil` to reach it for **all** version of android

- if it needs just rounded corners, we can use Coil's `RoundedCornersTransformation`
- if it needs rounded corners *with a border*, we can use  `BorderedRoundedCornersTransformation` https://gist.github.com/sergestanislavsky/bc8947c254c4238d85d5ff7e88245714
- if it needs just a circled image, we can use Coil's `CircleCropTransformation`
- if it needs a circled image *with a border*, we can use `BorderedCircleCropTransformation` https://gist.github.com/sergestanislavsky/52c76a5a0b61cf5f76e39724916c6f88

Example (pay attention `cornerRadiusPx` is zero there)

```
val model by remember(
        source,
        isRoundedImage,
        borderImageWidth,
        borderImageColor
    ) {
        mutableStateOf(

            ImageRequest.Builder(context).apply {
                data(source)
                if (isRoundedImage) {
                    transformations(
                        BorderedCircleCropTransformation(
                            dpToPx(context, borderImageWidth),
                            borderImageColor.toArgb()
                        )
                    )
                } else {
                    transformations(
                        BorderedRoundedCornersTransformation(
                            dpToPx(context, borderImageWidth),
                            0f,
                            borderImageColor.toArgb(),
                        )
                    )
                }
            }.build()
        )
    }

    AsyncImage(
        modifier = modifier,
        model = model,
        contentDescription = "Avatar",
    )
```

Comment: I needed it like 2 years ago but thanks

Comment: Heh sure! I posted it for someone who needs it now. Just share my experience

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the underlying API to apply the rounded corners is only available in S and there is no easy way to backport that for Glance.

You can either create a drawable with rounded corners in XML or modify at runtime your image and apply the corners there.

Answer (score 0):

Use: GlanceModifier.cornerRadius(8.dp)